# Expanding Pochammer symbols/Gamma function for simplifying expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, products

*TLDR:* How to expand gamma functions or Pochammer symbols in an arbitrarily long product?

**Some context**

I am trying to find out a closed-form expression for  $\langle r^\alpha\rangle$ for the non-relativistic Hydrogen atom. This is a generalisation of [this calculation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/561929/372582) from Physics Stack Exchange (which was for $\alpha=-1$) if somebody is interested. Using [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/02/01/0003/) formula I wrote the answer ("normans" in code). "norm" is just a normalization factor.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ans = ((Gamma[\[Alpha]] Gamma[n - \[Alpha] + \[Beta] + 1] Gamma[
         m + \[Lambda] + 
          1])/(p^\[Alpha] (m! n! Gamma[-\[Alpha] + \[Beta] + 
            1] Gamma[\[Lambda] + 
            1]))) HypergeometricPFQ[{-m, \[Alpha], \[Alpha] - \
\[Beta]}, {-n + \[Alpha] - \[Beta], \[Lambda] + 1}, 1] /. {\[Alpha] ->
      2 l + 3 + \[Alpha], p -> 1, m -> n - l - 1, 
    n -> n - l - 1, \[Lambda] -> 2 l + 1, \[Beta] -> 2 l + 1};
norm = (((2 Z)/(n a0))^3 ((n a0)/(2 Z))^(3 + \[Alpha])
    Gamma[ n - l])/(2 n Gamma[n + l + 1]);
normans = 
 FullSimplify[norm ans, 
  Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
    l \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
    0 < l <= (n - 1), \[Alpha] \[Element] Integers}]
```

The output is

```
(2^(-1 - \[Alpha]) ((a0 n)/
    Z)^\[Alpha] Gamma[-2 - l + n - \[Alpha]] Gamma[
    3 + 2 l + \[Alpha]] HypergeometricPFQ[{1 + l - n, 2 + \[Alpha], 
     3 + 2 l + \[Alpha]}, {2 + 2 l, 3 + l - n + \[Alpha]}, 
    1])/(n Gamma[2 + 2 l] Gamma[-l + n] Gamma[-1 - \[Alpha]])
```

*The problem and what I tried...*
However, if I want to reproduce the well-known result $\tag{2} \langle r \rangle~=~\frac{a_0}{2}\left[3n^2 -\ell (\ell+1)\right]$ i.e. take $\alpha=1$, first-of all direct replacing gives the erroneous answer zero because of the $\Gamma(-1+\alpha)$ in the denominator which blows up at negative integers. To get rid of that I took the limit $\alpha \to 1$, but that too had to be done after specifying particular values of $l$ (in terms of $n$ e.g. $n-1$, $n-2$, etc.) or both $n$ and $l$. When I do the math manually, the calculation is actually simplified when the gamma function is expanded using $\Gamma(n+1)=n \Gamma(n)$ and many factors cancel off from the numerator and denominator of the expressions. Hence the titular question.

I manually rewrote the result using Pochammer symbols as

```
FullSimplify[(2^(-1 - \[Alpha]) ((a0 n)/Z)^\[Alpha]  Gamma[
     3 + 2 l + \[Alpha]] Pochhammer[-\[Alpha] - 1, 
     n - l - 1] HypergeometricPFQ[{1 + l - n, 2 + \[Alpha], 
      3 + 2 l + \[Alpha]}, {2 + 2 l, 3 + l - n + \[Alpha]}, 
     1])/(n Gamma[2 + 2 l] Gamma[-l + n] ), 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
   l \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
   0 < l <= (n - 1), \[Alpha] \[Element] Integers}]
```

But Mathematica was unable to give $(2)$. Again, I get results when I specify $n$ and $l$ but not for the generic case. Btw, if you didn't know already $n$ and $l$ are supposed to be natural numbers and $l$ can take values from $0$ to $n-1$ only. $\alpha$ can be in principle any real but for simplicity I am restricting it to integers (both positive and negative).

Note---The ultimate goal is to produce a simplified formula if possible for a generic $\alpha$. But if $(2)$ which is valid only for $\alpha=1$ is derived, maybe I will be able to proceed on my own, so a partial answer covering only $\alpha=1$ but for generic $n$ and $l$ is also welcome.

I have seen some questions on this forum on simplification of gamma functions. However, none of them seems to solve my problem. But there might be duplicates which I missed, so feel free to point them out.